# Realm query doesn't update my adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm, adapter, rx-java

I need to receive the position using `LocationManager`, search in my realm database and finally udpate the `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. So I've made this `Observable`:

```
private void getLocation() {
    int GPSoff = -1;

    try {
        GPSoff = Settings.Secure.getInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
    } catch(Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(GPSoff == 0) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Couldn't get your current location")
                .setMessage("Do you want to enable location?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent onGPS = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(onGPS);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Location>() {
        LocationManager mLocationManager;

        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Location> subscriber) {
            final LocationListener listener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    if(location != null) {
                        Log.v("Location Changed", location.getLatitude() + " and " + location.getLongitude());
                        subscriber.onNext(location);
                        try {
                            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        } catch(SecurityException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                }
            };
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            try {
                Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if(location != null && location.getTime() > Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() - 2 * 60 * 1000) {
                    subscriber.onNext(location);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                } else {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                //   .requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                //       GPS_TIME_INTERVAL, GPS_DISTANCE, GPSListener);
                                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 10000, listener);
                                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 10000, listener);
                            } catch(SecurityException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch(SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(new Subscriber<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            logThreadSignature();
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    nearbs = realm.where(Airport.class)
                            .greaterThanOrEqualTo("latitudeDeg", (latitude - 0.5))
                            .lessThanOrEqualTo("latitudeDeg", (latitude + 0.5))
                            .greaterThanOrEqualTo("longitudeDeg", longitude - 0.5)
                            .lessThanOrEqualTo("longitudeDeg", longitude + 0.5)
                            .findAllAsync();
                    logThreadSignature();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Location location) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    });
}
```

the problem is that I don't see any changes in my adapter. This is adapter's code:

```
public class AirportsAdapter
        extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Airport, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        implements Filterable {
    Context context;
    String countryName;
    public static final int FILTER_MODE_A = 0;
    public static final int FILTER_MODE_B = 1;
    OrderedRealmCollection<Airport> listAirports;
    RealmResults<Airport> nearby;
    Realm realm;

    int NEARBY = 0;
    int AIRPORTS = 2;
    int nearbySize;
    int COUNTRY = 3;
    boolean countryFlag = false;
    int ALL = 1;

    public AirportsAdapter(Context context, OrderedRealmCollection<Airport> airports, RealmResults<Airport> nearby, Realm realm) {
        super(context, airports, true);
        this.context = context;
        this.listAirports = airports;
        this.realm = realm;
        this.nearby = nearby;

        Log.d("nearv", String.valueOf(nearby.size()));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == NEARBY) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.input_custom_item, parent, false);
            MenuHolder menuHolder = new MenuHolder(view);
            return menuHolder;
        } else if(viewType == ALL) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.input_custom_item, parent, false);
            MenuHolder menuHolder = new MenuHolder(view);
            return menuHolder;
        }

        if(viewType == COUNTRY) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.input_custom_item, parent, false);
            MenuHolder menuHolder = new MenuHolder(view);
            return menuHolder;
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.airport_show, parent, false);
            AirportClass holder = new AirportClass(view);
            return holder;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(getItemViewType(position) == NEARBY) {
            Log.i("ivt", String.valueOf(position));
            MenuHolder mHolder = (MenuHolder) holder;
            mHolder.type.setText("Nearby");
            mHolder.type.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Avenir-Medium.ttf"), Typeface.BOLD);
        } else if(getItemViewType(position) == ALL) {
            MenuHolder mHolder = (MenuHolder) holder;
            mHolder.type.setText("All");
            mHolder.type.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Avenir-Medium.ttf"), Typeface.BOLD);
        } else if(getItemViewType(position) == COUNTRY) {
            MenuHolder mHolder = (MenuHolder) holder;
            mHolder.type.setText(countryName);
            mHolder.type.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Avenir-Medium.ttf"), Typeface.BOLD);
        } else if(getItemViewType(position) == AIRPORTS) {
            AirportClass mHolder = (AirportClass) holder;
            Airport airport = listAirports.get(position - 1);
            String country = airport.getIsoCountry().toLowerCase();
            if(country.equals("do")) {
                country = "dom";
            }
            int imgID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(country, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
            Glide.with(context).load(imgID).into(mHolder.image);

            mHolder.des.setText(airport.getIdent());
            mHolder.name.setText(airport.getName());

            mHolder.des.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Avenir-Book.ttf"), Typeface.BOLD);
            mHolder.name.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Avenir-Book.ttf"));
        }
    }

    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if((position == 0) && (nearbySize != 0) && (!countryFlag)) {
            return NEARBY;
        } else if((position == 0) && (nearbySize == 0) && (!countryFlag)) {
            return ALL;
        } else if((position == 0) && (countryFlag)) {
            return COUNTRY;
        } else {
            return AIRPORTS;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if((nearbySize == 0) && (!countryFlag)) {
        //rivedere
            return 1 + listAirports.size();
        } else if((!countryFlag) && (nearbySize != 0)) {
            return 1 + listAirports.size();
        } else {
            return 1 + listAirports.size();
        }
    }

    public void filterResults(String text, int filterMode) {
        String txt = text;
        text = text == null ? null : text.toLowerCase().trim();
        if(text == null || "".equals(text)) {
            listAirports = realm.where(Airport.class).findAll();
        } else {
            if(filterMode == FILTER_MODE_A) {
                listAirports = realm.where(Airport.class).contains("name", text, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
                countryFlag = false;
            }
            if(filterMode == FILTER_MODE_B) {
                System.out.print(text);
                countryFlag = true;
                Countries country = realm.where(Countries.class).equalTo("name", txt).findFirst();
                countryName = country.getName();
                listAirports = realm.where(Airport.class).equalTo("isoCountry", country.getCode(), Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
            }
        }
        updateData(listAirports);
    }


    public Filter getFilter(int filterMode) {
        AirportFilter filter = new AirportFilter(this, filterMode);
        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return null;
    }


    private class AirportFilter
            extends Filter {
        private final AirportsAdapter adapter;
        private int filterMode;

        private AirportFilter(AirportsAdapter adapter, int filterMode) {
            super();
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.filterMode = filterMode;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if(filterMode == FILTER_MODE_A) {
                return new Filter.FilterResults();
            }
            if(filterMode == FILTER_MODE_B) {
                return new Filter.FilterResults();
            }
            return new Filter.FilterResults();
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            adapter.filterResults(constraint.toString(), filterMode);
        }
    }

    private class AirportClass
            extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name, des;
        ImageView image;

        public AirportClass(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            des = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.color);
        }
    }

    private class MenuHolder
            extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView type;

        public MenuHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.init);
        }
    }
}
```

how could I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: So you are saying that `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is not called? Or it is called but data has not arrived yet?

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy it's called but data has not arrived yet

Comment: I see a call to `findAllAsync()` just before `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Its name implies that result is not immediately available. Perhaps you need to wait for it to complete, or register a callback?

Comment: @YaroslavStavnichiy yes it's not immediately available. But first I try with .findAll( ) and adapter doesn't update too

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I think you should reconsider your `Observable.create()` because if this is RxJava1, then you're **not supposed to use** `Observable.create()`. There's `Observable.fromEmitter()`. Also, you shouldn't need to call `getActivity.runOnUiThread()` if you use RxJava, that's what `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` is for. Technically, fix your code first

Comment: thank you @EpicPandaForce, these are first times I've use Observable and so I'm a lot confused about observeOn and subscribeOn. But if I use mainThread() is there a risk to block the UI thread? Sorry for this question but it's important to understand

Comment: The code you run in `Activity.runOnUiThread()` is always executed on the UI thread, you're supposed to bind that into the Rx chain using `observeOn()`

Comment: but if I use .findAll( ) instead of .findAllAsync( ) could I block UI thread or not? @EpicPandaForce

Comment: I never said anything about having to use `findAll()`, I said you should fix your RX code

Comment: @EpicPandaForce is there a way to put RealmResults<Airport> airps = new RealmResult<>()? Because I couldn't instantiate it like List or Map

Comment: What? No, `RealmResults` are obtained by `realm.where(Airport.class)....findAll()` or `findAllAsync()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce could I contact you in chat?

Answer (score 1):

you can register a callback to be run when your RealmQuery finishes, in this callback you can then update your adapter as needed.

You are using the Async version which means it won't return straight away.

```
nearbs = realm.where(Airport.class)
                            .greaterThanOrEqualTo("latitudeDeg", (latitude - 0.5))
                            .lessThanOrEqualTo("latitudeDeg", (latitude + 0.5))
                            .greaterThanOrEqualTo("longitudeDeg", longitude - 0.5)
                            .lessThanOrEqualTo("longitudeDeg", longitude + 0.5)
                            .findAllAsync();
nearbs.addChangeListener(callback);

private RealmChangeListener callback = new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<Airport> results) {
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

See this link for more information on Realm Queries and callbacks.
https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#queries

Comment: The `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` adds a RealmChangeListener by default. But I'm not sure if he actually gets this far in the  code, the  Observable is just wrong

Comment: Ah ok, I haven't actually used the RealmRecyclerViewAdapter myself so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use

adapter.updateData(data: OrderedRealmCollection)

After your subscribe finish

```
nearbs = realm.where(Airport.class)
                        .greaterThanOrEqualTo("latitudeDeg", (latitude - 0.5))
                        .lessThanOrEqualTo("latitudeDeg", (latitude + 0.5))
                        .greaterThanOrEqualTo("longitudeDeg", longitude - 0.5)
                        .lessThanOrEqualTo("longitudeDeg", longitude + 0.5)
                        .findAllAsync();
logThreadSignature();
adapter.updateData(nears)
```

And also you should not notify your adapter update in newThread

Observer your realm query result on AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

And call adapter.updateData(result)

like this

```
Single.create<RealQueryResult> {
                //Do your query here
                val result = realm.where(....)
                it.onSuccess(result)
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                //Notify your adapter update here
                mAdapter.updateData(it)
            }, {
                //Handle exception here
            })
```